# MVC javascript with two ajax calls

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to MVC.  In my MVC app when the client initiates a View's javascript function call, I am proceeding where the javascript first calls a method in the controller (via ajax) where it updates session data/database data (a non-action controller method), then a second calls (but part of the same javascript) an action method in the controller to get another view.  I am doing this because I think it provides a clean separation between my session state updates/database updates (in the first call) and my viewmodel updates and view push (in the second call).  I can then always depend on the session data being correct and ready to be applied to a viewmodel in an action method.  Is it a "good" practice to use this approach in general?  TIA.

Comment: Any specific reason you need AJAX for this? Kinda sounds like you are dealing with multiple screens, which are handled by redirects

Comment: I'm dealing with sorting/filtering mostly with this scenario.